# Trying to apply a better refactoring in this rails code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have main 3 controllers, which has a function called **activation** that is taking the params from the form but before creating into the database, I have to merge some kind of hash into that params, Now am doing in this way:

```
class AccountsController < ApplicationController

  def activation

    activation_params = if valid_user?
      # This is a service, there I am taking this params and adding up one hash and returning the same 
      # params back
      Account::ActivationParamsModifier.new(params).call
    else
      params
    end

    @activations = Activation.new(activation_params[:activations])
    if @activations.save!
      # Code Here
    end
  end

  private

  def valid_user?
    # Valid User Check
  end
 end
end
```

I am trying to figure out one thing here, this below same code in 3 controllers and also I guess this code is not with a good refactoring. Any kind of suggestions to improve this? I know this small code but shows in different controllers. I am not sure this before_action is a good fit for this.

```
    activation_params = if valid_user?
      Account::ActivationParamsModifier.new(params, user_id).call
    else
      params
    end
```

Comment: I would move the valid_user? check into Account::ActivationParamsModifier and simply return the params unmodified if the user is not valid - that way you can just call Account::ActivationParamsModifier.new(params, user_id).call in every controller and you know that it will return the correct thing.

Comment: So even if the user is not valid that case also we are send the whole params into the function and returning, is that good? That was the way I did that before. Let say only 20% users are valid users so that time only need to call that service other 80% calls it should use the same params

Comment: In that case, create class method instead of instance method which saves memory in case you have large number of requests coming in.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/